# Multiselect plugin jquery not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I have been using multiselect API for the dropdown of multiple Select.

---

#### My HTML :

```
<select id="options" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

#### My JS :

```
render:function(){
    // $('#viewTemp').html(octopus.getQuestions()[0]);
    // console.log(questions);
    var htmlStr = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        htmlStr += "<option value="+(i+1)+">"+tags[i]+"</option>"
    };        
    //console.log(htmlStr);
    $(".options").html(htmlStr);
}
```

---

This isn't working. however whenever I do this ...

```
<select id="options" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="2">CSS</option>
    <option value="3">HTML</option>
    <option value="4">C</option>
</select>
```

... it does work!

Everything else (adding multiselect plugin etc.), I have done same as [multiselect plugin](http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/Articles/Multiple-Select-MultiSelect-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-using-jQuery.aspx)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have a class named `options`, you have an ID.

Comment: I spent 3 hours on this and might be getting too many negatives on this questions. Anyways, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of class selector in `$(".options").html(htmlStr);` you should use id selector `$("#options").html(htmlStr);`, because you don't have any class with name `options` but you have the `id='options'`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some quotation (and semicolon at the end) in this line:

```
htmlStr += "<option value="+(i+1)+">"+tags[i]+"</option>"
```

It should be:

```
htmlStr += "<option value=\""+(i+1)+"\">"+tags[i]+"</option>";
```